# Firebase binding in AngularJs

Tags: firebase

I am having issues binding to an object in firebase.  I am using AngularFire and the code in my Angular controller looks like this:

```
var firebaseCourse = new Firebase("https://torid-fire-1683.firebaseio.com/course-header/course-1");
$scope.course = $firebase(firebaseCourse);
```

This does successfully connect to firebase and return my data.  However, when the object is returned, it is embedded in another object like this:

```
{"-JDlZpk38i9YsSRoH0ce":{"description":"Course Description","name":"Course One"}}
```

Thus, when I bind to {{course.name}} in my view, it doesn't work, because the properties are embedded inside another object in the object that $scope.course is bound to.

How do I get around this?

Comment: How are you adding the data? The random IDs are generated when you use `$add` and is useful to  maintain distributed lists. So, instead of generating course names like 'course-1' yourself, you can let Firebase take care of it. Or, if you want to generate the course IDs yourself, don't use `$add` and use `$save` while writing the data instead.

Comment: I'm adding them through the HTTP REST API since there is no client for C#.

Comment: HTTP POST will push to a list. Use PUT and it won't generate the new ID.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.  If  you want to provide this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is exactly what firebase sends back. So your code is actually working. I believe that all you have to add is :
$scope.course = $firebase(firebaseCourse).$asArray();

If $asArray() still doesn't give you what you want, you can iterate over the object and create and array. So in your view you can do this:

In your view(html) - instead of - {{courses}} ----> {{getCourses(courses)}}

& in you controller

```
$scope.getCourses = function(courses) {
    var array = [];
    for(var key in courses) {
        array.push(courses[key]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

This way you will have an array or courses instead of a nested object. This will not effect the 3 way binding that is provided by angularFire

Hope this helps! Thanks